# Getting error when defining object Type '<object>' is not assignable to type in assembly script (thegraph development)

Tags: subgraph, assemblyscript, thegraph

I'm developing subgraph for indexing blockchain events, but I get error when defining and object

```
⠋ Compile subgraphERROR TS2322: Type '<object>' is not assignable to type 'i32'.

 export const FARMS_CONTRACT_NAMES = {
  BALANCER_LIQUIDITY: 'balancerLiquidity',
  GIV_LIQUIDITY: 'givLiquidity',
  GIV_ETH: 'givETH',
  GIV_HNY: 'givHny'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an object for your config you need to define a class for it, since AS doesn't have implicit objects:

```
class Config {
  BALANCER_LIQUIDITY: string;
  GIV_LIQUIDITY: string;
  GIV_ETH: string;
  GIV_HNY: string;
}

export const FARMS_CONTRACT_NAMES: Config = {
  BALANCER_LIQUIDITY: 'balancerLiquidity',
  GIV_LIQUIDITY: 'givLiquidity',
  GIV_ETH: 'givETH',
  GIV_HNY: 'givHny'
};
```

But exporting the values individually has it's benefits, too:

- Less source code
- You can import only parts of the config
- No Class overhead

Comment: Nice idea, good to know that, it would help me in other situations

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error changing that in this way solved my problem:

```
export const BALANCER_LIQUIDITY = 'balancerLM';
export const GIV_LIQUIDITY = 'givLM';
export const GARDEN_POOL = 'gardenPool';
export const GIV_ETH = 'givETH';
export const GIV_HNY = 'givHNYPool';
```

I think assembly script has problems with defining objects ( in the functions input parameters you cant use object {} )